# Check if element has parent recursivly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm have the following HTML and javascript::

```
<div id="1">
    <div id="2">
        <div id="3" class="clickable">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="4" class="clickable">

</div>

<script>
    $(".clickable").click(function ()
    {
        alert($(this).closest("#1").length == 0);
    });
</script>
```

When someone click on "clickable" element, I'm want to check:

1. If the clicked element is child of [div.id == "1"], alert(True).
2. Otherwise, alert(False).

For example:

1. When clicking id="3" - alert(True).
2. When clicking id="4" - alert(False).

Why this not working for me?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: What you have works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mowwzrut/ (aside from your `==` which should probably be `!=`)

Comment: @j08691 OP's code checks if `#1` is an ancestor, not the parent.

Comment: @Oriol - I think the OP is misusing the term "child" as his examples show that clicking 3 should return  true.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to check if closest is 1 or not so use

```
alert($(this).closest("#1").length != 0);
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1u1h2tL7/